# Unexpected blank lines between paragraphs and lists after \section

Tags: tex4ht

A `\section` will cause **unexpected** blank lines to appear between paragraphs and lists in a `odt` document created by TeX4ht. If `\section` is dropped, however, no extra blank lines will appear in thoses contexts.

My question is: What piece of code exactly in the configuration of `section`  is doing this? And why? (See code at the bottom.)

*(I'm asking this for educational purposes. I'm not reporting a bug. Nor am I dealing with a real world problem. I'm trying to understand how TeX4ht works.)*

## No `\section`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  Paragraph.

    \begin{enumerate}
       \item List
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

#### Good output:

[image]

```
   <!------no section---------------->
   <text:p text:style-name="Text-body">Paragraph. </text:p>
   <!------no blank line---------------->
   <text:list xml:id="list1" text:style-name="Enumerate">
    <text:list-item>
     <text:p text:style-name="Inside-enumerate">List</text:p>
    </text:list-item>
   </text:list>
```

## With `\section`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

  \section{My section}

  Paragraph.

    \begin{enumerate}
       \item List
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

#### Bad output:

[image]

By "blank line" I mean this: `<text:p text:style-name="First-line-indent"/>` in the third line:

```
   <text:h text:style-name="Heading-2" text:outline-level="2">1 Section</text:h>
   <text:p text:style-name="Text-body">Paragraph. </text:p>
   <text:p text:style-name="First-line-indent"/>
   <text:list xml:id="list1" text:style-name="Enumerate">
    <text:list-item>
     <text:p text:style-name="Inside-enumerate">List</text:p>
    </text:list-item>
   </text:list>
```

Notice that a blank line doesn't appear after the heading. It appears **later on**, i.e, after any paragraph which is followed by a list:

## Code:

Here is the configuration for `section` from `texmf/tex/generic/tex4ht/ooffice.4ht` (line 3460 ff)

```
\ConfigureMark{section}
   {\ifnum \c:secnumdepth>\c@secnumdepth \expandafter\:gobble
    \else  \thesection\space\fi }
\Configure{section}
   {\IgnorePar\EndP \HCode{<!--start of section-->}}
   {\IgnorePar\EndP \HCode{<!--end of section-->}}
   {\HCode{<text:h text:style-name="\csname a:Heading-2\endcsname"
                   \text:outlinelevel="2"  ><text:span
                   text:style-name="section">}\TitleMark\space
    \HCode{</text:span>}\IgnoreIndent}
   {\HCode{</text:h>\Hnewline}\par\ShowPar}
```

Comment: Make a copy of the file and then selectively remove bits of it until you find the bit responsible. At least, that's what I'd do.

Comment: I tried to find the solution, but failed. Just some observations: don't edit the file ooffice.4ht, but its literary sources: http://svn.gnu.org.ua/viewvc/tex4ht/trunk/lit/tex4ht-ooffice.tex?view=log you may need more files from http://svn.gnu.org.ua/viewvc/tex4ht/trunk/lit/ to compile that file with `htlatex tex4ht-ooffice.tex "xhtml, 4, sections+"`. after compilation, `.4ht` files are produced

Comment: literary sources use weird syntax, see http://michal-h21.github.io/mktex4ht/mktex4ht59.html for more info (and http://michal-h21.github.io/mktex4ht/mktex4ht2.html for some more info about `tex4ht`)

Comment: and regarding your problem, it seems that in every paragraph, some extra space is produced and paragraphs containing only space are produced then. it seems that HtmlPar, `\everypar`, or `\par` are influenced by `\section`, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: @michal.h21 Any news?